# Can't access multiple nested objest in linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Using EF6, MVC5, C#

*Updated per others recommendations in comments and post*

**Models** *(simplified for brevity)*:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ModelNum { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubCategory")]
    public Int32 SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public SubCategory subCategory { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    [ForeignKey("Manufacturer")]
    public Int32 ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public Manufacturer manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    [Display(Name = "Primary Category")]
    public int CategoryID { set; get; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Controller**  *Edited to simplify problem*

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   var items = from i in _context.ItemModel
                    .Include(i => i.Manufacturer)
                    .Include(i => i.SubCategory)
                    .Include(i => i.SubCategory.Category)
                    .Where(a => a.Description.Contains("usb") ||
                                a.Manufacturer.Name.Contains("bas") ||         // <-8
                                a.SubCategory.SubCategoryName.Contains("len")  // <-9
                                )
                    select i;

    return View(items);
}
```

---

As you can see I use three includes to access nested objects for a keyword search.  Hard coding a few where clauses demonstrates my problem.  If I remove either line 8 or 9 then it runs fine.  If I run as shown (all three where lines) I get the following error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression'.
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.IncludeExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)

---

What am I doing wrong with my includes or structure?

Stack Trace below:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression'.
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.IncludeExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)
System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitArguments(IArgumentProvider nodes)
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.IncludeExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)
System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(IncludeSpecification includeSpecification, Type resultType, LambdaExpression accessorLambda, Boolean querySourceRequiresTracking)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(QueryModel queryModel, IReadOnlyCollection`1 includeSpecifications)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(QueryModel queryModel, IReadOnlyCollection`1 includeSpecifications)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<CompileQuery>b__0()
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
Asp.ASPV__Views_ItemModels_Index_cshtml.<ExecuteAsync>d__25.MoveNext() in Index.cshtml
@foreach (var item in Model) {
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.<RenderPageAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.<RenderAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__56.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeResultFilterAsync>d__55.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAllResultFiltersAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeResourceFilterAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.<RouteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.Template.TemplateRoute.<RouteAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501329/linq-to-sql-combining-oring-multiple-contains-filters

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks for the link, I was hoping there was a way to avoid `PredicateBuilder`

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your query, but I suspect you have some issues with your model.  You are missing navigation properties, and the properties that tie one class to another.  Where is CategoryId in the ItemModel?  Where is the Category in the SubCategory class?  Why do you have both Category and SubCategory tied to ItemModel?  Shouldn't just the SubCategory be tied to the ItemModel in which you can then infer the Category?

Comment: Shouldn't those ICollections be marked virtual?  SubCategory has no Key.  Manufacturer has no Key.  ItemModel needs a ManufacturerId.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thanks for the help.  Good point about Category/ SubCategory.  EF6 creates the ID properties automatically if the name is the same as the subclass.  I verified this by looking at the database column names to verify they had 'ID' appended.  Code first also created the foreign keys correctly to relate classes together.  I added the virtual keyword and the missing [Key] 's  as you suggested but I think EF was able to overcome this already.  Unfortunately I still have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

With the ideas from @RobertMcKee comments, I did some testing in my pc. 
Here is the solution for your reference.

```
public class ItemModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ModelNum { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("Category")]
        //public Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }
        //public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SubCategory")]
        public Int32 SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Manufacturer")]
        public Int32 ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubCategory
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        public int CategoryID { set; get; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class Manufacturer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

And the filter is something like

```
var items = from i in context.ItemModels
                .Include(i => i.Manufacturer)
                .Include(i => i.SubCategory)
                .Include(i => i.SubCategory.Category)
                        select i;

            // Apply filter if search query was entered
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                string[] searchWords = searchString.Split(' ');

                foreach (var word in searchWords)
                {
                    items = items.Where(s => s.Description.Contains(word) ||
                                 s.SubCategory.Category.CategoryName.Contains(word) || 
                                 s.SubCategory.SubCategoryName.Contains(word) ||
                                 s.Manufacturer.Name.Contains(word) ||
                                 s.ModelNum.Contains(word)
                                 );
                }
            }
            return items;
```

The reason I commented Category in ItemModel is that EF Migration shows warnings below if we put both Category and Subcategory in ItemModel.

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ItemModels_dbo.SubCategories_SubCategoryId' on table 'ItemModels' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Since we have to put a ItemModel into a subcategory, then the property Category is removed from class ItemModel.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I took the time to implement all the changes and still get the same error.  I then created a new project and tried to implement only what was necessary but got the same result.  Would you be willing to drop a link to your project that you tested this in?  I'd like to take a closer look.

Comment: @PortlandRunner https://www.evernote.com/pub/yy_318/yyoussharingnotes  You will need to have SQL Express LocalDB (free download from MS) installed in your PC and restore nuget package when you open this project. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've been going through it carefully.  How and why did you create the indexes?  Were they manually created or did EF automatically create them?

Comment: @PortlandRunner All the indexes are created by EF in that project. Like the primary key, EF creates primary key according to naming convention. for example, if class name is called Entity, then property EntityId or Id will be primary key (you can also specify prirmary key by [Key] attribute). EF also use navigation properties to create foreign keys. some link may be helpful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx and

Answer (score 0):

Never did figure out why I could not access more than one sub class in the Linq query but I did come up with a work around solution using a helper class to flatten the structure.  Posting this to help anyone else in a similar situation.

**New, Additional Class**

```
public class ItemDisplay
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int m_ItemID { get; set; }
    public string m_ItemDesc { get; set; }
    public string m_ManfName { get; set; }
    public string m_CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string m_SubCategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[Authorize()]
public IActionResult SearchItems(string searchString)
{
    var ItemList = from i in _context.ItemModel
                    select new ItemDisplay
                    {
                        m_ItemID = i.ID,
                        m_ItemDesc = i.Description,
                        m_CategoryName = i.SubCategory.Category.CategoryName,
                        m_ManfName = i.Manufacturer.Name,
                        m_SubCategoryName = i.SubCategory.SubCategoryName,
                    };

    // Apply filter if search query was entered
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        // Sanitize search string
        searchString = searchString.Trim();
        searchString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(searchString, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z\._\s]", " ");
        searchString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(searchString, @"[\s]+", " ");
        string[] searchWords = searchString.Split(' ');

        foreach (var word in searchWords)
        {
            ItemList = ItemList.Where(s => s.m_ItemDesc.Contains(word) ||
                           s.m_ManfName.Contains(word) ||
                           s.m_CategoryName.Contains(word) ||
                           s.m_SubCategoryName.Contains(word)
                        );
        }
    }

    ItemList = ItemList.OrderBy(r => r.m_ItemDesc);
    return View(ItemList);
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<LabInventory.Models.ItemDisplay>

@* example *@

@foreach (var item in Model )
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_ItemDesc)
}
```

Now the search works across all members of the `ItemDisplay` class without problem.